# Excel, .End(xlToLeft).Address returns address of an empty cell

Tags: excel, vba

At the beginning of one of my subroutines I have some code that will define the dimensions of a data table that begins in Column B.

```
Dim TableHeaders As Variant: TableHeaders = "Table1[#Headers]"                  'Header row for the main data table
Dim MainDataTable As String: MainDataTable = "Table1"                           'Should be the main table on the BDDS
Dim MainTable As ListObject: Set MainTable = WsDB.ListObjects(MainDataTable)    'Mimics synax to call on the main data table as a variable (to make things cleaner)
Dim WholeMainTable As Range

Dim last_row As Long: last_row = WsDB.Range("A:A").Rows.Count
Dim last_row_col As Integer: last_row_col = WorksheetFunction.Match(WsDB.Range(TableHeaders).End(xlToRight), WsDB.Range(TableHeaders), 0) + 1 '+1 as the table starts in Column B
Dim first_header As String: first_header = WsDB.Range(TableHeaders).End(xlToLeft).Address

Set WholeMainTable = WsDB.Range(first_header, Cells(WsDB.Cells(last_row, last_row_col).End(xlUp), last_row_col))
```

The everything is working as expected except for when "first_header" is defined. End(xlToRight) gives me the correct location, yet End(xlToLeft) returns A53 instead of B53.

This code was working fine until I removed some rows above where the data table is but this code should have been able to account for that (which to be fair the row number is what it should be...)

I've double checked that there isn't anything in A53, and I've tried recording the code, selecting the table headers and manually doing ctrl (+ shift) + left. It stops at B53 as expected but when the code is run back in the macro... A53 displays again.

Comment: You are mixing table and worksheet properties and methods. When dealing with an Excel table, there is no need for `last row`, `first row`, `worksheet.Rows.Count`, `End(xlUp)` , etc. The Excel table has its own properties and methods e.g. `Range`, `HeaderRowRange`, `DataBodyRange`, `ListRow`, `ListColumn`, etc. If you could share what you plan to do with this table, I could write an example for you to get a feel for it. Anyways, you should study the [ListObject object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject).

Comment: I needed to define it in order to have an advanced filter applied to the whole table. Some methods I'd used before didn't return the whole data range if there was a filter applied to the table. 
Gove's solution fixed the issue for me. Thanks for taking the time to explain this though, and for the additional reading!! Will take your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though you are trying to set WholeMainTable to the range of the whole table.  If my reading of your code's intent is correct, there is a MUCH easier way:

```
Dim MainTable As ListObject: Set MainTable = WsDB.ListObjects(MainDataTable)
Dim WholeMainTable As Range
Set WholeMainTable = MainTable.Range
```

Comment: This.. Yea this works perfectly for what I need. Thank you very very much for the simple solution. As VBasic2008 suggested in another comment, I really should do a read more into the properties of the data types I'm working with to understand them better instead of trying to make work arounds.

Thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 1):

End always starts searching *after* the reference cell or top, left cell of the reference range.  So if you tell it to look to the left of B53, it will find A53.  If you started at C53 instead, it should find B53.